# load results on table while searching

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am not sure how I could approach this, I am just learning about tables.  I have the code below that filters an array as you type.  The search bar moves up and the controller goes dark below the search, however when I type the first letter, the results don't generate underneath.

This is a modification of the sample project from Apple.  Tablesearch

What am I missing?

Also the keyboard seems to drag behind when the new VC loads
Thank you in advance

```
//  itemsSearchViewController.m


#import "itemsSearchViewController.h"
#import "SearchRecipeViewController.h"
#import "firstAppDelegate.h"

@interface itemsSearchViewController ()


@end

@implementation itemsSearchViewController


@synthesize listContent, filteredListContent, savedSearchTerm, savedScopeButtonIndex, searchWasActive;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize itemsToPass;

/*
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle methods
*/

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //[super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"items Search";

    //write names of itemss to array
    NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"possibleitemss" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *content = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.listContent =[NSArray arrayWithArray:content];
    if([content count] == 0)

    {
        NSLog(@"nsma is empty");
    }
    NSLog(@"list contents%@", listContent);


   // NSLog(@"list content = %@", listContent);
        // create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.

    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.listContent count]];

        // restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
    if (self.savedSearchTerm)
        {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

        self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
        }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    //self.filteredListContent = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
        // save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [listContent release];
    [filteredListContent release];

    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView data source and delegate methods


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    /*
     If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, return the count of
     the filtered list, otherwise return the count of the main list.
     */
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
        return [self.filteredListContent count];
        }
    else
        {
        return [self.listContent count];
        }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
        {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
        }

    /*
     If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, configure the cell using the filtered content, otherwise use the main list.
     */
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    /*
     If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, configure the next view controller using the filtered content, otherwise use the main list.
     */

}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering
//as user types this is happening
-(void) filterResults:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.listContent];

    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.
        for (int i=0; i<[test count]; i++) {
            NSString *stringResult = [test objectAtIndex:i];
            NSComparisonResult result = [stringResult compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame){
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:stringResult];

            }
        }
    [self.filteredListContent sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];//sort alphabetically
    NSLog(@"filtered results = %@",self.filteredListContent);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{items

    [self filterResults:searchString];
    //[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:

    // [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

        // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
- (IBAction)itemsSelected: (id)sender{

    if ( self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showSearchRecipeView)] ) {
        [self.delegate showSearchRecipeView];

    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that one the below is out:

- The resource path is `possibleitemss` -- is that a typo?
- Have you verified that the arrays have been populated?
- Is your `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:` actually returning yes?

In other words, I'd step into each of these functions and watch the that the flow is behaving how you expected, and that your arrays are in fact populated.

Let me know if that helps.